# What consensual human experiments would provide the most geopolitical value?

Tags: society, scientific-development, geopolitics

In the world I envision here, some countries take a much less fundamentalist stance on human rights (maybe a more extreme version of China) than we generally take for granted.

For the purpose of geopolitical (economic, military, human capital generally) power, what experiments or extended scientific programs would such a nation try to run if they still insist on obtaining consent of experimental subjects themselves (so no children)?

Obvious things would be something like genetic engineering or certain drugs with untested side effects which stand to increase intelligence or any other desirable, but what other experiments would likely have a high impact?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, qeschaton, could please clear up what you mean by geopolitical value and how human research might contribute to it? Do you mean international economic value? Or the glory of achieving a spectacular scientific result? What sort of high impact do you have in mind?

Comment: I think if you leave out question 2 (perhaps do it in another topic if you thought this one went well) you've got yourself an interesting question. What sort of experiments could a nation run that people would volunteer for that are for example illegal in the EU or the US? Btw, you have to be more specific on that last point, several real countries could be considered "more extreme" than China, please define a good reference. Also perhaps exclude the classic: You can kill me, but for that my family has money.

Comment: PS: I think this one is very important: Consider dropping the "purpose" point. It doesn't really make sense on many levels. a) If we knew what experiments would give e.g. economic power, we wouldn't need to do them. It's a paradox you've got there. b) No experiment is that powerful. c) The limiting factor is and always will be money. I'm glad that you didn't include a point saying "money is irrelevant" because that means you are potentially a good world builder. There are pretty extreme places and they don't seem to do experiments with just humans that give them power or they would have power

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of scientific programs rather than isolated experiments. So a, b) I don't really think so. I would expect that there are many gains to be had from being able to actually do more medicine prototyping on actual people, or from checking to what extent we can interfere with child development. c) The US and EU are pretty conservative in terms of what kinds of experiments they allow, and the problem isn't money but morals. There are many experiments (or programs) you could run if you could actually find (well-paid) volunteers for them.

Comment: Check out Germany under the NAZI party, or North Korea.

Comment: @qeschaton If you already know the answer, why do you ask then? Perhaps you should ask in more detail if you already know what direction you want to go in.  Anyhow, check out the sandbox in the meta. You can ask questions there and have people help you with making them answerable https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions